# How do you upload a video to Google Drive using JS and Golang?

Tags: javascript, go, google-drive-api, video-streaming

I am trying to make a website like YouTube where you can upload and stream videos.

What I have in mind is to `POST` a `blob` on the frontend, and after that I have no clue other that I should probably use the Golang package [package drive](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/drive/v3?tab=doc). Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google-Drive has a REST-API you can leverage directly to [download/upload files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk#what_can_you_do_with_google_drive_api).

The pkg [google.golang.org/api](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.20.0/drive/v3?tab=doc) does simplify this, but its documentation is quite thin on examples.
So after [enabling the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-drive-api) on your target account, the flow is essentially:

```
import (
        "golang.org/x/net/context"
        "golang.org/x/oauth2"
        "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
        "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
        "google.golang.org/api/googleapi" // needed for googleapi.Field definition
)

// `clientIDfile` generated when enabling Drive-API on your account
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(clientIDfile)

// see what scope is right for you: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/drive/v3#pkg-constants
gscope := drive.DriveFileScope
gconfig, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gscope) // returns a `*oauth2.Config`

// load/parse user (API) token (requires a one-time oath step to create/store this token file)
tok := &oauth2.Token{}
err = json.NewDecoder(tokenFileHandle).Decode(tok)

ctx := context.Background() // replace with your app context if u have one
cli, err := gconfig.Client(ctx, tok)

service, err := drive.New(cli)
```

Armed with this `service` handle you can then access any of the documented drive APIs e.g.

```
folderID := "root" // replace with specific folder ID
pageSize := int64(1000)
queryString := fmt.Sprintf("mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '%s' in parents", folderID)
attrFields := googleapi.Field("nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, md5Checksum, size, modifiedTime, mimeType)")

flistQuery := service.Files.List().
                PageSize(pageSize).
                Q(queryString).
                Fields(attrFields)
```

will list all files (that are not folders) in your root directory, returning just attributes requested.